# fstream faster than fopen? and gets faster as buffers increase?

Tags: c++, io

I've been trying to write file data as fast as possible.

- I've increased the buffer size to reduce i/o operations.
- I've tested with both fstream and fopen.

For some reason fstream is faster than fopen.

- on a 64 byte buffer it's ~1.3 times faster
- on a 8192 byte buffer it's ~4.8 times faster.

I've been hearing that C's file I/O is faster (which makes sense)
`<fstream>` includes `<stdio.h>` yet i can't get fopen to perform as fast.

NOTE (old questions):

- my fopen was 2 times slower than fstream because i used fprintf (thanks [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin))
- fstream buffer wasn't changing since you have to set it before opening (thanks [Paul Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743288/paul-sanders))

also realized fstream.put(char) is faster than fstream << char
(otherwise fopen is faster than fstream if the buffer is < ~256)

Here's my testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

int filesize; // total bytes (individually "put" in buffered stream)
int buffsize; // buffer size

void writeCPP(){
    std::ofstream file;
    char buffer[buffsize]; file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer,buffsize);    // set buffer (before opening)
    file.open("test.txt",std::ios::binary);                             // open file
    for(int i=0; i<filesize; i++) file.put('a');                        // write bytes
    file.close();                                                       // close
}

void writeC(){
    FILE* file=fopen("test.txt","wb");                                  // open file
    char buffer[buffsize]; setvbuf(file,buffer,_IOFBF,buffsize);        // set buffer
    for(int i=0; i<filesize; i++) fputc('a',file);                      // write bytes
    fclose(file);                                                       // close
}

#define getTime() double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC // good enough

double start;

void test(int s){ // C++ vs C (same filesize / buffsize)
    buffsize=s;
    std::cout<<"  buffer: "<<buffsize<<"\t"<<std::flush;

    start=getTime();
    writeCPP();
    std::cout<<"  C++: "<<getTime()-start<<",\t"<<std::flush;

    start=getTime();
    writeC();
    std::cout<<" C: "<<getTime()-start<<std::endl;
}

#define MB (1024*1024)

int main(){
    filesize=10*MB;
    std::cout<<"size: 10 MB"<<std::endl;

    // C++ fstream faster
    test(64);   // C++ 0.86 < C 1.11 (1.29x faster)
    test(128);  // C++ 0.44 < C 0.79 (1.80x faster) (+0.51x)
    test(256);  // C++ 0.27 < C 0.63 (2.33x faster) (+0.53x)
    test(512);  // C++ 0.19 < C 0.56 (2.94x faster) (+0.61x)
    test(1024); // C++ 0.15 < C 0.52 (3.46x faster) (+0.52x)
    test(2048); // C++ 0.14 < C 0.51 (3.64x faster) (+0.18x)
    test(4096); // C++ 0.12 < C 0.49 (4.08x faster) (+0.44x)
    test(8192); // C++ 0.10 < C 0.48 (4.80x faster) (+0.72x)
}
```

Comment: I did not read how you did your measurements - You did them wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how should i do my measurements? it's definitely taking twice as long. try with the 1000mb.

Comment: There are so many people devoted to that - It's just a search away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i've even done the test using QueryPerformanceCounter and get the same results. i just didn't put that in this code to reduce size.

Comment: C++ streams have been under attack for - well, since they came into existence. They are better now. Not the zero-copying-ninja-streams one would want, but, pretty good. You bring measurements. Did you ever consider than *everyone* did the same thing you just did? Hint: I measured RPM in motors with Windows `QueryPerformanceCounter` 20 years ago ... it does not change one thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That comment is borderline incomprehensible.

Comment: Also, finding C++ streams to be slow is not an "attack".

Comment: @melpomene :-) I ... well, "borderline incomprehensible" is what I'll bring home Today - "-There? I Am"

Comment: Er, isn't the question claiming that C++ streams are *faster* than C streams?  How are C++ being "under attack" is *any* sense?

Comment: C++ streams have never been faster than  .. anything... noone is offended by that, I assume...?

Comment: @Puddle Do you get the same result if you use `fputc` instead of `fprintf`?

Comment: Feel free do copy my `mmap` tests (if those applies) that I did a while ago.

Comment: @jamesdlin thank you! that solved it. lol finally someone actually trying to help!

Comment: "`as fast as possible`" is a nice thing and good to strive for.

Who is your receiver?

Comment: @melpomene Oups .. I agree ... not only is there a border ... Sorry ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `WriteCPP`, you have to set the buffer before opening the file, like so:

```
std::ofstream file;
char buffer[BUFF]; file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, BUFF);   // set buffer
file.open ("test.txt", std::ios::binary);                   // open file
```

Then you get the sort of results that you might you expect (times are for writing 20MB with the buffer sizes shown):

```
writeCPP, 32: 2.15278
writeCPP, 128: 1.21372
writeCPP, 512: 0.857389
```

I also benchmarked `WriteC` with your change from `fprintf` to `fputc` and got the following (again writing 20MB):

```
writeC, 32: 1.41433
writeC, 128: 0.524264
writeC, 512: 0.355097
```

Test program is here:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/F2H2jcrMVsc5VNFf

Comment: Interestingly enough, on my rig (MacOS, Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4), -O2), the performance of cpp still outshines c considerably (by roughly the same ratio the OP is seeing). Expected results on wandbox [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RhXEpQV5FWqePPXH), actual results on my rig (same code) [here](https://pastebin.com/uSmJ4V4a)

Comment: @WhozCraig Looks like libc++'s `basic_filebuf` uses a `FILE*` under the hood, and that `FILE` has its own buffer that you can't change.  That means you'll get odd results with any buffer size that's not a multiple of `FILE`'s default buffer size (4096 on my copy).

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf` has extra overhead since it needs to scan its input string for format specifiers, so you're not quite doing an apples-to-apples comparison.

A better comparison would be to use `fputs` instead of `fprintf` or to use `fputc` and then use `file << 'a'` in the `iostream` version.

Comment: thanks again. i've updated the question to only be about the buffer now. (since i was still unable to get better performance by changing that)

Answer (score 0):

The only standard-defined behavior for `std::basic_filebuf::setbuf` is that `setbuf(0, 0)` sets the stream to unbuffered output, and even then I wouldn't count on it.

The *actual* behavior of `setbuf` varies wildly from implementation to implementation:

- libstdc++: `setbuf` only works if called before the file is opened.  Beyond that, it does what you would probably expect.  Every time the buffer fills you'll get one call to the underlying `write` syscall.
- libc++: `setbuf` can be called after opening a file, but before any I/O is done.  Every time the buffer fills you get a call to `fwrite` on an underlying `FILE*`.  That means that the output is still buffered using the `FILE`'s internal buffer.  There's no way to access that internal `FILE*` to `setbuf` or `setvbuf` on it, so you're stuck with the default buffer size (currently 4096 bytes, in glibc's implementation at least).
- MSVCRT: `basic_filebuf` shares its buffers with its underlying `FILE` object.  `setbuf` just passes the buffer you give it on to a call to `setvbuf` on an underlying `FILE*`.  May be called at any time, but will discard any previously-buffered data.